# "Array" Object Allocation

Tags: r, object

I have the following code that works:

```
  Dist1 <- table(RandArray[,1])
  Dist2 <- table(RandArray[,2])
  Dist3 <- table(RandArray[,3])
  Dist4 <- table(RandArray[,4])
  Dist5 <- table(RandArray[,5])
  Dist6 <- table(RandArray[,6])
  Dist7 <- table(RandArray[,7])
```

I would like it to be something like this:

```
for (AppInd in 1:7)
{
    Dist[AppInd] <- new("table")
    Dist[AppInd] <- table(RandArray[,AppInd])
}
```

Perhaps I don't need to do the above, maybe I could alter:

```
AllDist <- table(RandArray[,])
```

Is there a way to avoid the for loop?

Thank you for helping a newbie "R" coder.

Richard Rogers

Update:

```
SequenceCount <- 100000
ApproachCount <- 7

RandArray <- matrix(NA_integer_, nrow = SequenceCount, ncol = ApproachCount, byrow = FALSE)
```

Comment: Could you try `Dist <- apply(RandArray,2,table)`? Also, please show a sample of `RandArray` (or just give the output from `dput(RandArray)` if it is not too large)

Comment: Hi Marat,

The code you supplied worked perfectly.
Thank you very much!!!

Richard